How can we store all document from Asp.net File Upload Control and store directly inti SharePoint list or library
How can we store from ASP.NET Application File Upload Control directly to SharePoint List / Library?
I have tried using Rest API call from ASP.net application but no luck. Getting

401 unauthorized access while accessing Request Digest in Your AJAX Request.

$.ajax({
    url: "https://your-sharepoint-site/_api/contextinfo",
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var requestDigest = data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;
        console.log("Request Digest:", requestDigest);

        // Now use this requestDigest in your subsequent AJAX call
        performAjaxRequest(requestDigest);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log("Error retrieving request digest:", error);
    }
});

function performAjaxRequest(requestDigest) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://your-sharepoint-site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('YourList')/items",
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": requestDigest
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.YourListListItem' },
            'Title': 'New Item Title'
        }),
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Item created successfully:", data);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("Error:", error);
        }
    });
}

